# PM2/NodeJS API with mongoDB index problems

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pm2, mongodb-indexes

I'm trying to deploy multiple `NodeJS` rest **APIs** in the same Ubuntu VPS using `PM2`, those APIs are used to serve data from different `MongoDB` database in the same local hosted db server.

I do encounter some port problems, but i do change it in every application to solve the problem. After that a strange `mongoDB` error appears.

```
API listen on port 3001
Connected!
MongoError: Index with pattern: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 } already exists with different options
    at /var/app/my-project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:593:63
    at authenticateStragglers (/var/app/my-project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:516:16)
    at Connection.messageHandler (/var/app/my-project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:552:5)
    at emitMessageHandler (/var/app/my-project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:309:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/app/my-project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:452:17)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:597:20)
```

Now, the API keeps restarting and slows the all system. Please can anyone guide me threw this, note that i'm just maintaining the app. i'm not the developer and i'm not so familiar with mongo databases.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check on which field you have your text index defined. Right now mongodb allows only one text index per collection

```
db.collection.getIndexes()
```

You will get some thing like this

```
 {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_fts" : "text",
            "_ftsx" : 1
        },
        "name" : "desc_text",
        "ns" : "some.ns",
        "weights" : {
            "title" : 1
        },
        "default_language" : "english",
        "language_override" : "language",
        "textIndexVersion" : 2
    }
```

now if you want to scope in other columns also to use this index simply drop this index

```
db.collection.dropIndex('desc_text');
```

and then recreate it by including all columns you want to be covered by text index,

```
db.collection.createIndex({
    title:'text'
      ...
});
```